# What video connector for a mid-2012 macbook pro to External Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

What are the different (and the best) option for connecting my mid 2012 Macbook pro to an external monitor. Three connections I know of are VGA, HDMI and DVI. What is the difference and what cables do I need? Are there any other options I can consider? Are there any adaptors that let me switch between VGA and DVI?

Comment: DisplayPort. Your machine will have either Thunderbolt or Mini DisplayPort; either will work to a DisplayPort connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best connector is obviously one which matches your monitor.

If you are getting a new monitor, most now use `HDMI`.

HDMI and DVI-D are very similar, and dual adaptors are common. The main difference is lack of sound on DVI.

`VGA` is an analog connection, and effectively obsolete, but you can get VGA adaptors for a Mac.